# Shared service used in two component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services

I have a service for working with the db, where I can get/add/delete products.
I'm using this products.service.ts in 2 components since I need to get products in 2 places in my application,

Therefore I want to switch my service to observable/subject so I can subscribe to it and it will be synced in the 2 places.

The thing is that I'm struggling making that switch for 2 days now.. if anyone could help me with that I'll be grateful !

It's like I'm using a different product "state" in each component because when I'm adding a product on one component it's updating only this component and the second is still the "old" one.

Here is my products service for the moment.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from '../products/product.model';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8001/api/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {
  private model = '';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  all(sellerId, token): Observable<Product[]> {
  this.model = 'products'
    return this.http.get(this.getUrlById(sellerId), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
    .pipe(map((products:Product[]) => products))
  }

  create(product, token) {
    this.model = 'product'
    return this.http.post(this.getUrl(), product, {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}});
  }

  update(product, token) {
    this.model = 'product'
    return this.http.put(this.getUrlById(product.id), product, {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}});
  }

  delete(productId) {
    return this.http.delete(this.getUrlById(productId));
  }

  private getUrl() {
    return `${BASE_URL}${this.model}`;
  }

  private getUrlById(id) {
    return `${this.getUrl()}/${id}`;
  }
}
```

For the moment I added the all function as an observable, but nothing else I tried worked so I left it as it was before. I am new with rxjs and angular in general (always worked with React in my previous works)

Thank you infinitely for those who will reply !!

**This is the products.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AppSettings } from '../../app.settings';
import { Settings } from '../../app.settings.model';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { ProductsService } from '../../shared/products.services';
import { ProductDialogComponent } from './product-dialog/product-dialog.component';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [ ProductsService ]  
})

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    public products: Product[] = null;
    public searchText: string;
    public page:any;
    public settings: Settings;
    public firestore: any;
    public token = this.cookieService.get('token')
    public id = this.cookieService.get('id')
    constructor(public appSettings:AppSettings, 
                public dialog: MatDialog,
                public productsService:ProductsService,
                public router:Router,
                firestore: AngularFirestore,
                private cookieService: CookieService){
        this.settings = this.appSettings.settings; 
        this.firestore = firestore;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.token) {
            this.getProducts()
        }
    }

    public getProducts(): void {
        if(this.id) {
            this.productsService.all(this.id, this.token)
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products)
        }
    }

    public createNewVersion(product:Product) {
        if(this.token) {
            this.productsService.createNewVersion(product.id, this.token)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.getProducts()
            })
        }
    }
    
    public deleteProduct(product:Product){
        console.log(product.id)
    //    this.productsService.delete(product.id);
    }

    public openProductDialog(product){
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProductDialogComponent, {
            data: product
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if(result) {
                console.log('worked')
                this.getProducts()
            }
        })
    }

    public callModulePage(productId) {
        this.router.navigate(['/modules'], {state: {data: productId}})
    }

}
```

**Here is the sidenav component that show the products**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, ViewEncapsulation, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/shared/products.services';
import { AppSettings } from '../../../../app.settings';
import { Settings } from '../../../../app.settings.model';
import { MenuService } from '../menu.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ProductDialogComponent } from '../../../../pages/products/product-dialog/product-dialog.component';
import { Product } from '../../../../pages/products/product.model'
import { ModulesService } from '../../../../pages/modules/modules.service'
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vertical-menu',
  templateUrl: './vertical-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vertical-menu.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [ MenuService, ProductsService, ModulesService]
})
export class VerticalMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public settings: Settings;
  public products: Product[] = null;
  public productID = null
  public modules = {};
  private token = this.cookieService.get('token')
  private id = this.cookieService.get('id')
  public isModuleOpen = {};
  constructor(public appSettings:AppSettings, public menuService:MenuService, public router:Router, public productsService:ProductsService, private cookieService: CookieService, private modulesService:ModulesService, public dialog: MatDialog) { 
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.parentMenu = this.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == this.menuParentId);  
    if(this.token) {
     this.refreshProducts()
    }    
  }

  redirectTo(uri, moduleId, moduleName, product) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
    this.router.navigate([uri], {state: {data: {moduleId, moduleName,product}}}));
  }

  showModules(productId) {
    this.modulesService.getModules(productId)
      .subscribe(m => {
        this.modules[productId] = m
        if(this.modules[productId].length > 0) {
          if(this.isModuleOpen[productId]) {
            this.isModuleOpen[productId] = false
          }else {
            this.isModuleOpen[productId] = true
          }
        }
      })
  }
  
  public openProductDialog(product){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProductDialogComponent, {
        data: product
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if(result) {
          this.refreshProducts()
        }
    })
  }
  public refreshProducts(){
    this.productsService.all(this.id, this.token)
    .subscribe(res => this.products = res)
  }
 }
```

**There is a button in both component that opens a add-product-dialog component, here the dialog component with the create function**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { Product } from '../product.model';
import { ProductsService } from '../../../shared/productss.services'
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-dialog',
  templateUrl: './product-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class ProductDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public form:FormGroup;
  public passwordHide:boolean = true;
  public token= this.cookieService.get('token')
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProductDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public product: Product,
              public fb: FormBuilder,
              private productsService: ProductsService,
              private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: null,
      name: [null],
      shortname:[null],
      description: [null],
      overview: [null],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.product){
      this.form.setValue(
        {
          id: this.product.id,
          name: this.product.name,
          shortname: this.product.shortname,
          description: this.product.description,
          overview: this.product.overview
        }
      );
    } 
    else{
      this.product = new Product();
    } 
  }

  addProduct(product) {
    if(this.product.id) {
      if(this.token) {
        this.productsService.update(product, this.token)
        .subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result)
        })
      }
    } else {
      if(this.token) {
      this.productsService.create(product, this.token)
      .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
      }
    }

  }

  close(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: share the html files to understand how all 3 relative components are related to each other

Comment: the html files ?

Comment: Making a stackblitz so I can share the code

Comment: yes the html files

Comment: there is a sidenav component where we can see all the products and a products component which is used in the products page, but the two html files are not related because I declared a products variable in both and both are using a <div ngFor="let protocol of protocols"> which is probably why they are not synced

Comment: just share as a code the other 2 component.ts files and html. We can't help you if we don't see what you already have

Comment: I already suspect your error but I must first see your 2 other components

Comment: Thank you I'm editing my post with the 2 components right away

Comment: The html files are only using a for loop over protocols there is no other logics inside

Comment: pls check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the logic of what you want to achieve. 2 components always seeing a fresh list of products even when the change was invoked from 1 of those components. You also want to suppress that functionality inside a single service.

The problem with your implementation is that each component subscribes to a different Observable which is created every time the `all()` method is invoked. The method brings an observable that carries that fresh information of products on that time line and then ends. The other component has previously subscribed to another observable of another past timeline which returned and ended.

You can however make both components constantly listen to your `Subscription`. Then when 1 component asks for a fresh list of products, you retrieve it with http but instead of returning a new Observable (*which the other component will not know*) you emit a fresh value with the same `Subscription` that both components listen to.

That translates to the following

```
export class ProductsService {
  private model = '';

  //keep that Subscription as a reference here
  getAllProdObserv :  BehaviorSubject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]); 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //When this method get's called it will create an observable and when that observable is ready to be opened it will emit the value by your public subject
  all(sellerId, token): Observable<Product[]> {
  this.model = 'products'

    this.http.get(this.getUrlById(sellerId), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
    .pipe(map((products:Product[]) => products)).subscribe( (products) => this.getAllProdObserv.next(products));

  }
```

That way your other 2 components will always be listening on your Subject and see the values that it emits.

Then on **SideNav**

```
export class VerticalMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public settings: Settings;
  public products: Product[] = null;
  public productID = null
  public modules = {};
  private token = this.cookieService.get('token')
  private id = this.cookieService.get('id')
  public isModuleOpen = {};
  constructor(public appSettings:AppSettings, public menuService:MenuService, public router:Router, public productsService:ProductsService, private cookieService: CookieService, private modulesService:ModulesService, public dialog: MatDialog) { 
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //You subscribe on the same Subject that will always exist but each time will emit the value of a fresh list
    this.productsService.getAllProdObserv.subscribe(res => this.products = res);
  }
```

And then on **products.component.ts**

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    public products: Product[] = null;
    public searchText: string;
    public page:any;
    public settings: Settings;
    public firestore: any;
    public token = this.cookieService.get('token')
    public id = this.cookieService.get('id')
    constructor(public appSettings:AppSettings, 
                public dialog: MatDialog,
                public productsService:ProductsService,
                public router:Router,
                firestore: AngularFirestore,
                private cookieService: CookieService){
        this.settings = this.appSettings.settings; 
        this.firestore = firestore;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //Again you subscribe on the same Subject that will always exist but each time will emit the value of a fresh list
        this.productsService.getAllProdObserv.subscribe(products => this.products = products)
    }
```

So by now `products.component.ts` and `sidenav.component.ts` will always listen to a single observable (actually Subject) and every emitted event will be rendered to both components.

Your service will emit a new fresh list of products each time the method `all` is called.

Then on `products.component.ts` the `getProducts()` will just make your service to emit a new value of the fresh products that both components will continuously listen to.

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
       this.productsService.getAllProdObserv.subscribe(products => this.products = products)
    }

    public getProducts(): void {
        if(this.id) {
            this.productsService.all(this.id, this.token);
        }
    }

    public createNewVersion(product:Product) {
        if(this.token) {
            this.productsService.createNewVersion(product.id, this.token)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.getProducts()
            })
        }
    }

    public openProductDialog(product){
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProductDialogComponent, {
            data: product
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if(result) {
                console.log('worked')
                this.getProducts()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Also the same in your **sideNav** component

```
export class VerticalMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public settings: Settings;
  public products: Product[] = null;
  public productID = null
  public modules = {};
  private token = this.cookieService.get('token')
  private id = this.cookieService.get('id')
  public isModuleOpen = {};
  constructor(public appSettings:AppSettings, public menuService:MenuService, public router:Router, public productsService:ProductsService, private cookieService: CookieService, private modulesService:ModulesService, public dialog: MatDialog) { 
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.parentMenu = this.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == this.menuParentId);  
    if(this.token) {
     this.productsService.getAllProdObserv.subscribe(res => this.products = res);
    }    
  }

  redirectTo(uri, moduleId, moduleName, product) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
    this.router.navigate([uri], {state: {data: {moduleId, moduleName,product}}}));
  }

  showModules(productId) {
    this.modulesService.getModules(productId)
      .subscribe(m => {
        this.modules[productId] = m
        if(this.modules[productId].length > 0) {
          if(this.isModuleOpen[productId]) {
            this.isModuleOpen[productId] = false
          }else {
            this.isModuleOpen[productId] = true
          }
        }
      })
  }
  
  public openProductDialog(product){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProductDialogComponent, {
        data: product
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if(result) {
          this.refreshProducts()
        }
    })
  }
  public refreshProducts(){
    this.productsService.all(this.id, this.token);
  }
 }
```

Edit: Just to add some info for OPs that face this thread and see the long discussion under. This answer here is enough to solve the issue. The Issue that we faced under discussion found to be that the service was not registered as singleton across the whole application but was registered again for different modules and different components in providers tag. After fixing that the behavior was as expected.

Comment: thank you so much for the effort. I'm gonna rewrite it to my code but I think it will work like this. Thank you infinitely !

Comment: now when I call theall function (which subscribe to getAllProdObserv.next(products)) I get an empty array instead of my products, any idea on why ?

Comment: empty array is the starting value of the Subject. It is normal that you see it. However it should have called the backend at some point and return actual array of products. Check this line `this.http.get(this.getUrlById(sellerId), {headers: {'Authorization' : Bearer ${token}}})
    .pipe(map((products:Product[]) => products)).subscribe( (products) => this.getAllProdObserv.next(products));,` I think the pipe with the map can be removed. It does not do anything useful. Also check that this method is actual called and it's not something missing with token

Comment: I suspect that something goes wrong with this http call and you never get inside `subscribe( (products) => this.getAllProdObserv.next(products))`

Comment: No, it's just that the getProducts is never call so I added it on the ngOnInit. But there I still need to refresh to see the new product on the other component :(

Comment: but it is already on the ngOnInit on the answer provided here. Pls copy what you have done so far so we can find the error

Comment: I tried to remove the products variable from both component and move it to the service, and therefore in the html instead of calling the forloop "let product of products" I change it to "let product of productsService.products" but still the same I don't get synced data ..

Comment: Yes but in your answer you removed it. Anyway its there now, I'm sharing the code

Comment: This is not a workable app but you can see the 3 folders products-shared-sidenav https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-efstdt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Here is your error without even seeing your code `I tried to remove the products variable from both component and move it to the service` When you move a variable to the service the component will stop tracking changes. Therefore it will not render any changes that happen in tha variable in the UI. it is the default changes detection mechanism of angular

Comment: Thank for the info, but then I re-moved them to each component, it was just for seeing what would happen. In the code you can see that they are in the right place, and even like this it still doesn't show the changes in the UI.. I'm gonna cut my head off it's been three days I'm working on the same issue :(

Comment: Try the following `all(id, token): Subscription {
  this.model = 'products_author_id';
  return this.http.get(this.getUrlById(id), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
  .subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
    console.log("inner subscribe called");
  })
  }` Then run it again and check if it prints the message. I think that it does not get inside that subscription

Comment: "inner subscribe called" is being called twice when I start the app, then when I add a product it's being called once

Comment: now replace the static text `console.log("inner subscribe called");` with `console.log(products)` Does it always print the products?

Comment: Yes it does, and the component itself change with the new produt, but not in the sidenav

Comment: And vice versa when I add a product on the sidenav it doesnt get effect on the product component page

Comment: I suppose you have moved products variable inside of both components. How do you use this variable in the html?

Comment: It its two different variables.. but on both components they should keep track of the observable with your method

Comment: I am posting a video of whats happening

Comment: just post how those 2 components are related. I mean all the html codes to understand when each component get's initialized

Comment: !!!! the products are the protocols so you wont get lost :p !!! Here is the UI video https://youtu.be/xPPV0tBvJ7M ,
 I'm sending you the HTML of the two files right now

Comment: I am checking everything once again

Comment: Try once the following in each ngOnInit method  `ngOnInit() {
    if(this.token) {
      this.productsService.getAllProdObserv.asObservable().subscribe(res => this.products = res); } }`  I mean add the asObservable() before actualy subscribing on ngOnInit on both components

Comment: Didn't change much. Again thank you for helping me

Comment: Somewhere is a hole. This structure has worked for me in the past.  Try one last thing. `ngOnInit() {
    // this.parentMenu = this.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == this.menuParentId);  
    if(this.token) {
     this.productsService.getAllProdObserv.subscribe(res => {this.products = res; console.log("inside ngOninit subscription for component 1});
    }    
  }` Add a similar method for console.log() in the second component ngOnInit. Then try once again and check the logs. Are both logs available?

Comment: It can be that the update is done and just angular does not reflect those changes in the UI

Comment: Depending on which component I'm adding a product the console log appear, but not the second one. I'm gonna check on the product-dialog component maybe there is something wrong there but, if both component are observing to the observable and are subscribing to it it should do the trick like you are saying.
Also I'm gonna quit angular and make ng serve again

Comment: Also check how those 2 components are related? Are they different elements of the same html parent component?

Comment: You should check when angular needs to construct that component

Comment: They aren't from the same html parent component, should I move it to the app component so it will be available everywhere ? Because I told myself the app component doesn't need to loop over these products so no need for it to have the products service in it

Comment: try to remove the constraint  `if (this.token) { }` from both components on ngOnInit

Comment: If on application start the token is not available as you must call the backend to retrieve it, it can be that some component never gets on point in NgOnInit to make the subscription for `getAllProtObserv`

Comment: It didn't change anything, should I add in productService a 

get products(){
return this.getAllProtObserv.getValue()
}

and change in my *ngFor="let product of products" to "let product of productsService.products" ??

Comment: I added also a products$ = this_getAllProdObserve.asObervable() in the service

Comment: I tried to move the subscription from the ngOnInit to the constructor, didn't help too

Comment: Maybe it's a import problem ? Should I import the productService to the app.module or to any other place ?

Comment: have you tried to remove the constraint  `if (this.token) { }` and let the other code in ngOnInit? Give this a try first

Comment: I removed if (this.token) Didn't help, the thing is that I HAVE to call the all() function from the component I want to update for it to have actually an update on the UI. You are telling me that no matter where I call productsService.all() in my app, all the subscription sould update ? For the moment its when I call productsService.all() from a component it only update this component itself

Comment: If the other component has already subscribed to that subject it should be notified also. That's why I asked you to remove this.token. Maybe it does not get to subscribe on ngOnInit because this.token is available only later when the http call to retrieve it is done.

Comment: `this.token` will not be available during NgOnInit, therefore it does not subscribe.

Comment: Yes but a cookie stay even on browser refresh, anyway now I removed the this.token condition and still nothing. I tried to add a products$ = allProdObserv.asObservable() and subscribe to it instead on the ngOnInit, still nothing. Even on the *ngFor i replaced it by "let product of productsService.prodcuts$ | async" on both component and still don't see update :(

Comment: I also added a get products() {return this.allProdObserv.getValue()} and replaced the *ngFor to this one and still no updates

Comment: I'm on angular 11 btw

Comment: have you registered somewhere in some module or component your service in the `providers` tag?

Comment: Yes I tried to add it in all of the modules (app.module, products.module) there is no module for the sidenav component, should I create one and add the service in there ?>

Comment: remove it from everywhere.  `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})` is enough and should be provided as singleton to everyone.

Comment: In your way you have created different instances for that service for different modules and components. Therefore we don't speak for the same instance and hence it does not work

Comment: OMG you solved it by removing the service from all the providers ! You solved my nightmare since 4 days now ! Thank you so much !! you can edit/add this answer I'll accept it as the right one in case anyone struggle with that. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

    
create(product, token) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      })
    }
    return this.http.post(this.getUrl() + "/create", product, httpOptions).pipe(
        map(response => {
           return response;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: You suggest only to replace my create function by this one and both components will be synced ?

Comment: You can also make a common method for all requests. Can you please create a stackblitz so that we can solve your problem easily?

Comment: Yes but the app use a template theme and use a local python server so it makes it hard to create a stackblitz, I'm trying right now

Comment: I can't make it on stackblitz.. I guess I'll have to search by myself, but my real strugle is how do I use the same products variable in two different component ? Because for now if you see the post I create one variable in each component so I need to refresh the page to see the effect in the second one